# Where is Henri Lebesgue's grave?

Tags: mathematics, famous-people

Where is Henri Lebesgue buried?

Full name: Henri Léon Lebesgue

He was a famous French mathematician. He died in 1941 in Paris, France.

There is no entry for his name on findagrave.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to a notice published around the time of his death, Henri Léon Lebesgue is buried in the cemetery of [Gouvieux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouvieux), a small town in the Oise department of France.

H. Fehr, "Henri Lebesgue 1875-1941", *L'Enseignement mathématique*, Vol. 38 (1939-1940), pp. 330-332 ([scan online](https://www.e-periodica.ch/digbib/view?pid=ens-001:1939:38#477)):

> Nous avons la profonde douleur de faire part à nos lecteurs de la perte que la Rédaction de « L'Enseignement mathématique » vient de faire en la personne de M. Henri Lebesgue, Membre de l'Institut, mort à Paris le 26 julliet 1941, à l'âge de 66 ans, de suites d'une grave maladie. L'inhumation s'est faite au cimetière de Gouvieux (Oise).

The online records of the cemetery administration of Gouvieux show a [plot for a Lebesgue family](https://www.gescimenet.com/WD180AWP/WD180Awp.exe/CONNECT/HFGescimeNet211?alias=gouvieux-cimetiere-60270&page_site=Visu_Concession&mode_appel=Concess&lieu=1933&defunt=0&type=s&alias=gouvieux-cimetiere-60270) in the Cimetière Ancien (Old Cemetery) of Gouvieux.